# Emacs auto-complete for slime not allowing pop-up selection

Tags: emacs, autocomplete, slime

On Emacs 24.3.50.1 I have auto-complete mode up and running (by using source code and following their setup, plus other's added suggestions). Then I installed ac-slime from ELPA-land (Version: 20131005.1126), which puts it in ~/.emacs.d/elpa/ac-slime-20131005.1126. However, the .emacs usage code doesn't seem to make any specific note of where this directory is. I suspect I don't really have ac-slime working properly as I can't choose from pop-up suggestion list with return key. Any ideas how to get it working?

Comment: Works here, did you add a hook for `slime-mode` and / or `slime-repl-mode` to add `ac-slime` to `ac-sources`?

Comment: Being new at this, I'm not sure what you mean. Please elaborate.

Comment: To give an example, I have Emacs open with a .lisp file in one buffer, the slime repl in the other. The lisp side pops up suggestions and I can scroll down and hit return to complete. But on the slime-repl side no key seems to complete my selection. I can only tab, then type in to break "ties" then tab again etc. I'd like the slime-repl side to emulate the lisp completion behavior.

Comment: https://github.com/purcell/ac-slime in the "installation" section of the readme it says to copy a bit of code into Emacs configuration file (typically `.emacs`), do you have that code in it? Actually, if you can just post the contents of `ac-sources` variable when in the REPL, for example, that would be enough to tell whether you have it installed or not. To do it: `M-: ac-sources` then `C-x b *Messages*` and coy the last line.

Comment: (ac-source-filename ac-source-slime-simple ac-source-abbrev ac-source-dictionary ac-source-words-in-same-mode-buffers)

Comment: Well, then you certainly have it installed, `ac-source-slime-simple` is the source that comes from that package. Now, try this and tell what you see, in the REPL: `(pp ac-completing-map)`, switch to `*Messages*` buffer and see if you have `(return . ac-complete)` in the keymap object printed there.

Comment: I get a lisp (sbcl) error in slime: The variable AC-COMPLETING-MAP is unbound.
   [Condition of type UNBOUND-VARIABLE]